# Assigning the content of a txt file on server to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my problem (which is rather simple).

How can I assign the content of a file on my server to a javascript variable ?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
var count= <?php echo file_get_contents("compteur.txt");?>
```

But it doesn't funciton. BTW: I spent two hours on google already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If content of the file is not not a numeric value then you have to use `'` or `"` as below

```
var count= '<?php echo file_get_contents("compteur.txt");?>';
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `'` before the `<?`. And what if the file contains `'` or newlines?

Comment: What about the second part of my comment?

Comment: Thx for your help. But the console still tells me : "unexpected token <"

Comment: This is indeed an issue. You will either have to make sure that you can define whats in the .txt (therefore no newlines, pure JS-ready text) or implement methods that correctly parse the content of the text..

Comment: Ok now its functionning. Thx :)

Comment: @JLRishe Yes `'` or newlines will also create problems, one of method would be escape or replace them like `var count = '<?php echo str_replace(array("'", "\n", "\r"), array("\'", " ", " "), file_get_contents("compteur.txt")); ?>';`

Answer (score 0):

Simply outputting the file's contents in between single quotes will present a lot of pitfalls. If you're using PHP 5.2 or higher, you can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), which should be a lot more foolproof:

```
var count = <?php echo json_encode(file_get_contents("compteur.txt")); ?>
```

`json_encode` will take care of surrounding the value in quotes, so you do not need to put quotes before and after the PHP snippet.

On versions of PHP before 5.2, you can use this less robust technique for escaping the value:

```
function escapeJsonString($value) { # list from www.json.org: (\b backspace, \f formfeed)
    $escapers = array("\\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
    $replacements = array("\\\\", "\\/", "\\\"", "\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "\\f", "\\b");
    $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
    return $result;
}
```

[Source](http://www.pontikis.net/tip/?id=5)